# How to add menu to the particular row selected?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primefaces, contextmenu

I have a p-contextmenu and p-table, I want to menu should be visible only when that particular row is selected. Right now with the below code once a row is selected, I am able to view the menu options on row right click, due to my condition: if(this.rowSelected)==null;
Html file:

```
<p-contextMenu #cm [model]="items" appendTo="body"></p-contextMenu>
<p-table #dt [(selection)]="rowSelected" [value]="listOfRows" [contextMenu]="cm" [dataKey]="id" [columns]="columns" (contextmenu)="onContextMenuSelect($event,cm)">
```

Ts file:

```
onContextMenuSelect(event,contextMenu){
 if(this.rowSelected==null){
 
  contextMenu.hide();
 }
}
```

This only checks whenever a row is selected then on right click of any rows menu appears, I want to make it sure that for that particular row itself right click menu should appear and on right click of other row but without selection menu shouldnt appear.

Comment: How is it different from the behaviour given in https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/contextmenu ?

Comment: I would first like to select the row, then enable right click for that particular row. This works -> https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/table/contextmenu , for non selection of row then press right click and view the menu.